# Re-download a SNAPSHOT version of a dependency using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following lines in my `build.sbt` file.

```
resolvers += "specs2 snapshot repo" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.7-SNAPSHOT" % "test"
```

Now if the snapshot has changed (is this reasonable at all, that a maven SNAPSHOT version changes without its version number changing?), how can I tell sbt to download the new version? Using `update` does nothing.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

you should try :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.7-SNAPSHOT" % "test" changing()
```

`changing()` will specify that the dependency can change and that it ivy must download it on each `update`.

Maybe you could also try to define your repository using `ivyXML`. Something like this :

```
ivyXML :=
  <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="specs2 snapshot repo" changingPattern="*-SNAPSHOT" m2compatible="true" root="http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots"/>
  </resolvers>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I expected that this option doesn't have to be specified but can be infered from the *SNAPSHOT* string. Will sbt/ivy only check the checksums and don't download again if the jar has not changed?

Comment: Ivy defines a `matchingPattern` that you can use when defining a resolver. This `matchingPattern` gives you the ability to define a pattern (for example `"*-SNAPSHOT"`) for artefacts that will eventually change over the time. You should try to define a resolver with this attribute using `ivyXML` setting, maybe SBT will consider it.

Comment: In 0.12.1 at least, you don't need to specify changing: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html the last line: "There is no need to mark SNAPSHOT dependencies as changing() because sbt configures Ivy to know this already."

Comment: Does specifying a wildcard directly in the Ivy spec work? `"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "*-SNAPSHOT" % "test"`