# How to tell SBT to resolve managed artifacts

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.0

Is there a command in the SBT console that forces it to resolve artifacts (especially, re-resolve SNAPSHOT dependencies)? The only way I know of now is to run clean and then compile (or start), but this takes much longer and isn't always necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark the needed dependencies to re-check them on `update`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.10-SNAPSHOT" % "test" changing()
}
```

[Re-download a SNAPSHOT version of a dependency using SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224907/re-download-a-snapshot-version-of-a-dependency-using-sbt)

Comment: I don't think the `changing()` is needed anymore in sbt 0.13.x.  Should be set by default...

Answer (score 1):

The `update` command should help.

From [the task's documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html#sbt.Keys.update):

> Resolves and optionally retrieves dependencies, producing a report.

See [Dependency Management Flow](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html).

What's more important, `SNAPSHOT` dependencies are in their nature `changing()` so there's no need to add anything after ModuleID to mark them as such. Every `update` is supposed to resolve them against the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `update-classifiers` is what you are looking for? Otherwise, try the `tasks` command to see what's available.