# Why SBT custom plugin resolution is slow

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I have my custom SBT plugin and I use it in my project. In case of any change of the plugin I make `publish-local` and then I build my project and sbt writes in console `Resolving <my-plugin-name>;0.2-SNAPSHOT ...`. This resolution takes long time(about minute).

Why it takes so much time to resolve a custom sbt plugin from local repository and how to fix this ?

**Update**

Please note, that I have slow network connection via proxy-server. So probably it's the issue. But in this case I wonder why sbt needs network if I have my plugin published-local. And if it's the issue how to eliminate network round trip ?

Comment: It would be well worth while setting up a local repository proxy like Nexus. This would optimize your network traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dependency is a SNAPSHOT, then sbt will try to resolve it from the remote repository in case it has been updated.

See also [Re-download a SNAPSHOT version of a dependency using SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224907/re-download-a-snapshot-version-of-a-dependency-using-sbt)