# Redownload snapshot dependency in sbt

Tags: sbt, coursier

This looks like a duplicate of [Re-download a SNAPSHOT version of a dependency using SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224907/re-download-a-snapshot-version-of-a-dependency-using-sbt).  However, the comments there say that

> There is no need to mark SNAPSHOT dependencies as changing() because sbt configures Ivy to know this already.

I am using SBT 1.9.7, and perhaps `sbt` is telling Ivy, but I am clearly seeing it reference an out-of-date jar after `test` and then `show externalDependencyClasspath`.  The jar is in the `~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/`, so perhaps Coursier does not support this or the Ivy configuration code never got applied to Coursier.

In fact, I am finding it nearly impossible to get `sbt` to use the newest version of the dependency.  I have deleted the directory in the cache, added and removed `changing()` from the dependency statement, run `sbt update` several times, and it is still referencing the old jar.

I looked at the Nexus server in a browser and the new version is there, right alongside the old version.

How do I get it to download the new version of the snapshot?